# How to integrate Facebook sdk in titanium for ios and Android?

Tags: facebook, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Hi am working on an app Using Appcelerator Titanium, in which i have to integrate Facebook sdk. i am so confused on using which sdk have to use .. whether choose the ios or android or javascript sdk. Another query is , whether if have to create a separate project for ios and Android. or a single project is enough. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can either check the Facebook support shipped with Titanium SDK: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

Or you can check out this module on github: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook

Comment: Actually those are the same. That one on GitHub is the one bundled with the Titanium SDK and documented at that first URL.